# Get the location of a blob in OpenCV using C++

Tags: c++, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHVCR.jpg)

The image shown is the difference between two images. All I want to do is get the location of the white part. I want to do this because I want to be able to highlight the place where the difference is on the original image.

I am thinking about using clustering or blob detection or maybe just locating the brightest or whitest pixel in the image.

What method do you think would be the easiest? Is there another method I haven't though of?

Comment: If it is as simple as white on black detection,  just scan picture until you hit white. There will be better choices of how to scan, maybe random location rather then top left to bottom right

Comment: Also, do you need to hit the centre if the blob?  If this is the case, sum all the values in each column, to make an array on "x" then sum all the values in each row, to make an array on "y". The most intense (highest value) elements of x and y array will give you the rough coodinates of the center.

Answer (score 0):

Use the findContour method to find the closed contour in the image.

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours( BinaryImage, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

And you can draw that contours using **drawContours** .

And the variable **contours** contains the coordinates making that particular contour. You can display it by the following command

```
for(double i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    cout << contours[i];
    drawContours( OutputImage, contours, i, Scalar(0,255,0), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
}
```

Comment: If this answer helps you. Up vote it. So that i will be useful for other users.